# How to encourage the user to check details before submission

Tags: validation, password, confirmation, captcha

I'm upgrading a legacy financial application which requires users to re-enter their password before a transaction is submitted. I need to remove the password check since I'm migrating users to a new Identity Provider where this is no longer possible.

The advice from our business area is that the password check 'slows' the user down and forces them to think about the transaction details, avoids users accidentally clicking a submit button etc.

What is a common approach to encourage users to check details on page before continuing? captcha? secret question? email a PIN? forced time delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would not think that stretching time using forced delay or captcha is a very effective technique here - the user would probably start wondering why does captcha exist on earth at all, i think what you really want is to try and enforce the user to **double check** their entry before submitting an application form.

### Overview Before Submit

[image]

This is a similar pattern - with some utility differences - that is used in an e-commerce checkout, once the users have inputted their data, navigate them to a mediator page/view that provides them an overview where you ask them to **double check** their entries before the final submit.

And if you want to take it to the next level, you can add a dialog box on checkout that asks "Are you sure you have checked your entry" but that will most likely freak them out.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I was asked a similar question also for a financial software. My manager came to me asking how can we make **Deleting a record HARDER**. He wanted the users to read the warning before deleting. So I suggested using this design (It is what we currently use):

[image]

The user needs to check the checkbox before deleting. The actual implementation **disables the Delete button** till the checkbox is checked.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### Request to type another time the main element of the form

If the submission is critical (a mistake would have a significant negative impact on the user), you could add friction to your process by requesting the user to type one more time the main element of the form (i.e. the amount). Some applications use that method to confirm the deletion of an item.

[image]

It should incite the user to double check all the form, and not only the requested information.

### Delayed submission

Another option that involves less friction would be to delay the submission of the transaction and showing a confirmation screen : the transaction is sent after 30 seconds / 1 minute (you should adapt the time depending on the amount of fields to check), unless the user presses a "cancel" button. Gmail uses that solution after sending an email : you have 10 seconds to change your mind and cancel the email.

[image]

Source of the examples : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/friction-ux-design-tool/